# Q: How to change language PDF page indicator?

Tags: swift, indicator, pdfview

I want to change the language of the page indicator, it should be german and not english. If you scroll inside of a pdf file it shows you "1 of 6" that's what i want to change.

Any ideas?

```
import UIKit
import WebKit


class PDFViewController: UIViewController {
    var pdfName: String?
    @IBOutlet weak var wkWebView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let pdfFilePath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: pdfName!, withExtension: "")
        let urlRequest = URLRequest.init(url: pdfFilePath!)
        wkWebView.load(urlRequest)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you set your device/simulator to german?

Comment: yes my iPhone is set to german.

Comment: Füge mal in Xcode unter Project -> Info -> Localizations German hinzu.

Comment: Hat funktioniert, nicht auf anhieb, aber das war die Lösung. Danke ! Retterdesdialogs anwser was perfect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Xcode Project -> Info -> Localizations add German
```

was the answer!
Thanks @Retterdesdialogs